# How to use regular expression in Linux to output number?

Tags: regex, linux

How do you output only the number of words in `/usr/share/dict/words` that begin with any letter, let's say `j`?

I was hoping to use `egrep 'J*' /usr/share/dict/words`, but does not work well.

Comment: You might want to learn some basic regex first.

Comment: What does "does not work well" mean exactly?  How does it not work?

Comment: its like shows all the lists but doesn't show lists that start with J but I think i want to do list in number of words.

Comment: @kee23 You instructed `grep` to print lines that contain any number of `J`s, including zero. You could have just taken two minutes to read the manual, or just googled it. *sigh*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your words are one on each line, then your solution is very close.

```
grep -ci '^j' /usr/share/dict/words
```

The `^` symbol means "start of line". `-i` flag means case insensitive search, `-c` means only report the count.

Comment: You're right. I don't usually use `-c`, but it is much more efficient. Updated accordingly.

Comment: If they're not on one line, and taking 'words' to mean strings separated by a space: `sed 's/ /\n/g' words.txt | grep -c '^j'`